# Can a Constructor Override its Instance

Tags: java

I'm working on a game, and this question came up: if a variable is set to an instance of a class, and that classes constructor sets the variable, what does the variable end up as? For example:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static MainInterface mainInterface;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainInterface = new SubClass1();
    }
}

public interface MainInterface {
    public void method();
}

public class SubClass1 implements MainInterface {
    public SubClass1() {
        MainClass.mainInterface = new SubClass2();
    }
    public void method() { }
}

public class SubClass2 implements MainInterface {
    public void method() { }
}
```

So, in this example, would mainInterface be an instance of SubClass1 or SubClass2?

Comment: Best answer: What happens when you test this?  Also, perhaps you should be using a static factory method and keep the constructors private.

Comment: You can step through this in a debugger and see how it works

Comment: It will be `SubClass1`, because the `SubClass2` will be overwritten when the constructor is finished.

Comment: "*would mainInterface be an instance of SubClass1 or SubClass2*" both, that depends on which point/time of execution we are.

Comment: @Pshemo The OP said the point was "end". It's not ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it and find out! :) A simple `System.out.println(mainInterface.getClass())` will print out the class value.

I'm fairly certain that the process works like this:

- SubClass1's constructor is called, setting mainInterface to a new
  SubClass2 object.
- SubClass1's constructor finishes and is assigned to mainInterface, resulting in mainInterface being the newly created SubClass1 object.